# Installation of an AC Drive on a Mixer - Help

Tags: motor, frequency, variable

We have a 30hp 1440rpm AC motor installed on a mixer.
Motor Pulley: 6"
Machine Pulley: 20"
According to my calculations, the mixer runs at 432rpm.

Operating Procedure: 
The mixer is loaded with approximately 200kg of raw material feed, along with water and several mixing compounds. The motor is then started by a "Star Delta" Starter.

Due to the high load in the mixer, the motor is unable to move in the "Star" Phase. The connected ammeter's needle touches the roof, so the current consumption is higher than 80amps (the max that the ammeter can measure).

When the Starter puts the motor in "Delta", it starts with a jerk and the ammeter reads about 60amps. After the initial 2-3 minutes, the mixer settles down and the motor's current consumption hovers between 30 and 40amps.

---

Considering that we install an AC Drive for the above motor, I have the following questions:

1. Would an AC Drive be able to maintain the necessary torque at extremely low motor RPMs?
   I intend to have the AC drive slowly accelerate the mixer to the desired rpm, thereby giving the mixture enough time to settle down and reduce the need for high current consumption.
2. Would a V/F control type AC Drive suffice for the above application?
   I am specifically looking at Siemens Sinamics V20.
3. What kind of energy savings would an AC Drive bring for the above application?

Other Details about Connected Power Supply: 
V: 440V
F: 50Hz

---

I would greatly appreciate any and all assistance. 
Please excuse me if any assumptions are wrong, I'm not well versed with this field. 
Thank You.

Comment: You might want to link to the motor controller's datasheet  - and the motor's too, if you have that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any data regarding the motor or access to its controller's datasheet. It's very very old. Can you try and answer some of the queries without access to this data? I realize it can be difficult. Thanks

Comment: No I can't. I have no idea of the current capabilities of the drive OR the starting current of the motor.

Comment: For the details of the drive: https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/948/103599948/att_67109/v1/SINAMICS_V20_Getting_Started_072012_en-US.pdf

Comment: Got this from Siemen's website: SINAMICS V20 – an overview of the technology
Voltage and power range:
1AC 200 V - 240 V, ±10 %
3AC 380 V - 480 V +10 % / -15 %
0.12 kW - 30 kW (0.17 hp up to 40 hp)
Control modes:
V/f, V2/f, FCC, V/f multi-point

Comment: 1. Extremly low RPM is allways an inssue for inducton motors. How low is low for you and for how long do you need to stay there? 2. Yes. 3. For your start scenario, not much. In light load application where you cn descrease speed to minimise losses, some.

Comment: @winny 1. We would need the mixer's blades to run at 400-500rpm, once the initial torque load is overcome. Once at that speed, they need to be there for about 30 minutes. I reckon, we can change the pulley ratio to ensure that the motor's fan is running at a decent speed for cooling. | 2. Thanks.| 3. If I get the pulley ratio to 0.5 (Motor:Machine) and run the motor at 900rpm, I would be able to get the mixer rpm to 450 (ideal). Do you estimate any savings in this setup?

Comment: Since the startup torque is your main problem. It is best to look at a socalled Closed Loop Vector control system. See my answer.

Comment: @winny, I asked for "extremely low rpms" because I thought that since the motor is unable to run initially due to high torque load, we can perhaps accelerate it slowly by using an AC Drive. The main point being, if the motor speed is say, 10%, would the torque be 10% too or would it be the same as when the speed is 100%. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have almost all torque available down to low RPM. Perhaps not 10 % of the RPM, but close to it. There are many issues at low RPM and high torque and prolonged times. For once, most motors have their fans on the same axle and hence same RPM. A short spin-up is fine but you need more cooling if you want to run it like that for long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a V/F control system could be an approach. However with only V/F control the regulator can not see if the motor is acctually turning. 
One step further is adding an encoder to the system so the regulator can see that the motor is turning.
In both situations the available starting torque will be more or less 150% at low frequencies (3Hz)

A different approach could be OLV (Open loop vector control). Here the motor can realise a torque of about 200% of their rated torque at very low frequencies. Also here an encoder is possible turning the system into an CLV closed loop vector control. Here a torque control mode is possible. Thereby the motor is controlled at torque rather then motor speed.

Try to understand the principles first and then look at your situation.The Closed loop vector control would have my preference for your mixer. For this approach you can look at the SINAMICS G120.

For your specific questions.

1. CLV can work in a standstill condition and would deliver enough torque during startup. You can compare this with a DC motor.
2. V/F might be enough but is not sure. For the other possibilties see above.
3. I do not think that energy savings can be achieved. The motor has to deliver its energy whatever the situation is.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I just need a clarification. I think till now, I've been working with a flawed assumption that the relationship between torque and motor speed depends solely on the motor itself and is independent of the drive. If I'm absorbing everything correctly, I need to look for a drive that offers greater starting torque at very low frequencies?

Comment: That is correct.  Since your main problem is the starting torque you need torque control at very low frequencies. I have experience with mixer motors up to 300 kW mixing Oppanol using clv.

Comment: Dont forget the cooling. An external driven fan is probably required. I the situation I have worked with we used watercooled motors

Comment: The motor is going to run at extremely low frequencies for about 10-15s. After that, we would need to increase it to about 900rpm to get the mixer running at our target RPM of 400-500. (Pulley ratio of 0.5 assumed).

Motor Frequency|Motor RPM|Mixer RPM

Say, 3Hz|90rpm|45rpm TO 31.25Hz|937.5rpm|468.75rpm

The mixer is to remain at that speed for the next 30 minutes.
Do you feel the need for external cooling in such a case?

Comment: Secondly, is there any cost advantage of lowering the frequency and the resultant motor RPM? I can play with the pulleys to change the motor RPM if needed. For us, energy efficiency is of prime importance.

Comment: It is best to run the motor at nominal speed whenever possible. At low speed and high torque the motor will get hot.

Comment: With high torque the motor will get hot and needs cooling. Keep the motor running at nominal speed as soon and as long as it can. I do not know the motor but in many situations a external fan can be fitted in place to the shaft mounted fan. I believe that you will not gain on efficiency. But only a complete calculation between now and the expected new situation can give that answer.